# query for nextval sequence generation taking long time

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a process in application where we insert 1000+ records in application. There is a attribute in the table as mentioned below.

```
@Index(name = "_IDX_UNIQUE_UUID", columnNames = {"UUID"})
@Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false)
private Long uuid;
```

During populating the entity class the value is set as following

```
entity.setUuid(service.getNextUuid());
```

which calls this method in service class:

```
public Long getNextUuid() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select nextval('seq_xxxx_uuid')");
    //This takes lot of time to execute
    Obj result =  query.getSingleResult();

    return ((BigInteger) result).longValue();
}
```

To get next value from sequence, it takes around 200-700 ms. This accumulates to several minutes if I try to insert 1000+ records. Moreover, the query is quite simple and executes in less than 1ms if I execute it in a database client.

I am using postgresql 9.4-1206-jdbc4, hibernate 4.2.0.Final and Spring 4.2.5.

Comment: obvious question : why simulate a mechanism that JPA already has? use `@GeneratedValue`. If you really need to do it manually (e.g non-Id field and your JPA provider is too basic and doesn't allow you to do generated value on non-Id fields) then can you not grab the JDBC Connection from your JPA provider (the one I use allows this) and invoke directly? maybe that would give a faster reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slow, because you're going through all the layers of security and consistency checks of a JPA full query, plus you're creating a new NativeQuery object every time and not doing it though a `@NamedNativeQuery`, thus taking even more time to evaluate.

The solution is to annotate the column with:

```
@Id
@Index(name = "_IDX_UNIQUE_UUID", columnNames = {"UUID"})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_xxxx_uuid_gen", sequenceName = "seq_xxxx_uuid", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_xxxx_uuid_gen")
@Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

You do want that `allocationSize` to be the same value as the `increment_by` value of your sequence, or you'll have other problems after the first persist.

If you need to use that Id for multiple objects (say it's part of a composite key, but only part of it is serial-generated), just grab it from the first one after persisting it.

Edit:
Alternatively you can forego the SequenceGenerator and use this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

It may be faster, if the generated query is properly optimized and uses `java.sql.Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` upon insert.